# Dual space of mean-free Sobolev space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, duality

I am considering the space $V:=\{v \in H^1(\Omega): \int_\Omega v = 0\}$ of mean free functions. What is the dual space of this space? Is the dual space given by $D:= \{f \in (H^1(\Omega))^*: \langle f, 1\rangle=0\}$? If so, why?

I understand that the dual space $H^1(\Omega)^*$ of $H^1(\Omega)$ consists of all linear functionals, i.e., of mappings from $H^1(\Omega)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, I understand that $\langle f,v\rangle$ denotes the duality pairing between $H^1(\Omega)^*$ and $H^1(\Omega)$ and can be computed by $\langle f,v\rangle = \int_\Omega f v$.
Then, the dual space $V^*$ of $V$ should contain all linear functions from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. In my opinion, it should hold, that if $f \in D$ is a constant function, then $\langle f,v \rangle = \int_\Omega fv = f \int_\Omega v = 0  \quad \forall v \in V$. How can I define this property of $f$ in $V^*$ and is this equivalent to $\langle f,1 \rangle=0$?

Frieder

Comment: Every element $f\in H^1(\Omega)^*$ is a linear functional acting on $V$. However, notice that if $f, g \in H^1(\Omega)^*$ such that $f - g = C$, then $\int fv = \int gv$ for every $v \in V$, so $f$ and $g$ should represent the same element in $V^*$.

Comment: Are you not happy with $V^*$ being just the restriction of $(H^1)^*$ to test-functions in $V$? For example in finite dimension we know the dual of $\mathbb R^3$, and if $V=\mathbb R^3\cap\{x_3=0\}\cong \mathbb R^2$ then the dual is just the restriction of $(\mathbb R^3)^*\cong \mathbb R^3$ to the hyperplane. Is that not enough? As in Willie Wong's comment, the full characterization is then that if two cotangent vectors $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ and $f'=(f'_1,f'_2,f'_3)$ have the same "projection" $(f_1,f_2)=(f_1',f_2')$ then $f=f'$ as elements of $V'$ (which has an obvious geometric interpretation)

Comment: In abstract terms, if $V$ is a closed subspace of $W$, then $V^*$ is isometric to the quotient space $W^*$ mod the annihilator of $V$. In your case, $V$ is the kernel of a continuous linear functional $\ell$, hence the annihilator consists of the span of $\ell$. Please note that it is a little touchy to say that the duality ``can be computed by $\langle f,v \rangle = \int_\Omega fv$''; in dimension 1 the functional $f$ might be a point evaluation.

Comment: For anyone looking for a short, compact answer to this question, see the nicely written section 2.1.1 in F. Dubois et al 2003: doi:10.1016/j.matpur.2003.09.002